# HttpServletRequest getCookies() always returns null for iOS devices

Tags: ios, http, jakarta-ee, glassfish

When I am calling the HttpServletRequest getCookies() method in a JAX-RS application under Glassfish 3.1.2 it always returns null with iOS devices (both 5 and 6).

As far as I can tell I have enabled cookies on the iOS devices, and they are stored on the devices, but they are not send over with the request.  Cookies work fine with desktop browsers.

Any thoughts on how to make the cookies come over so that getCookies doesn't return null?

Comment: An issue related to the `domain` setting on the cookie, maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, and if that were the case I would think that it wouldn't work on the desktop browsers, would it?

Comment: Just in case you are not doing so already, I would like to recommend to use Charles proxy to properly debug the HTTP communication of your device and compare it with the communication that seems to work as expected.

Comment: @TofuBeer - In general yes, although I think I vaguely recall something about the security policy in mobile Safari being different in some way.  I can't seem to find a specific reference though, so perhaps I'm imagining things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out that the path of the cookies was missing the / at the beginning. Some browsers rejected it as invalid, others accepted it but would never return it, and others accepted it and returned it.

I finally used the following code to track it down:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;


public class CheckCookies 
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv ) 
        throws Exception
    {
        HttpMethod method;
        HttpClient client;

        method = new GetMethod(argv[0]);
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.executeMethod(method);
    }
}
```

Which threw an exception telling me that the cookie was invalid because it was `XXX` not `/XXX`